# Automatically drop variables with p-value greater than 5% from linear regression model

Tags: python, linear-regression

I want to drop variables (using loop) from my linear regression model.

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm

train_x = sm.add_constant(train_x)
lm = sm.OLS(train_y,train_x).fit()
```

Comment: you almost certainly don't want to be doing analysis like this, see for e.g.: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/unpublished/p_hacking.pdf and similar papers

Comment: If you are going to try this approach, make a test where the highest p-value is dropped first, and repeat until all are less that 5%. Sometimes this works better than dropping all that are greater than 5% at the same time. This can be automatically done in a loop and can sometimes be useful.

Comment: I want to drop the variables with highest p-value first

Answer (score 0):

```
# Filter only those with a P-value less than 5% - this will be a pandas series
keep_pvals = lm.pvalues[lm.pvalues <= .005]
```